# How to access remote MicroSoft SQL Server database from a stored procedure in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need to access a remote Microsoft SQL Server database from a stored procedure in MySQL database.

I googled and found that there is a way to access a remote MySQL using federated tables. But I couldn't find anyway to do access MS SQL Server. My exact requirement is, I need to write a stored procedure which can duplicate all the tables and data from a remote MS SQL server database to a local MYSQL database.

Please help..

Comment: *I need to write a stored procedure which can duplicate all the tables and data from a remote MS SQL server database to a local MYSQL database* Use some migration wizard or ETL or some other right tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

In short this cannot be done with MySQL federated engine. However you can setup a link from the remote MSSQL server to a MySQL table using the linked server feature of the MSSQL server.

If you can set this up you can have a scheduled job populate the MySQL tables from the MSSQL server side.

I have done the above setup and it is not to difficult.

I would also investigate some ETL tool to do this as it sounds like a ETL job and not something you want to run via stored procedures.

Good Luck.